# Como identificar un equema de base de datos postgres con hibernet?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Buenas tardes,

tengo el siguiente inconveniente
Necesito enviar un correo a un usuario específico dentro de mi base de datos, dicho usuario se encuentra en un esquema específico diferente al esquema púbico.

Cómo puedo identificar el esquema al que dicho usuario pertenece?

Actualmente dentro de mi código está lo siguiente:

```
     package framework.hibernate;
     import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
     public class SchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver 
      {
      private static String tenantIdentifier = "public";

     @Override
     public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
     return tenantIdentifier;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
     }

      public void setTenantIdentifier(String tenantIdentifier) {
       SchemaResolver.tenantIdentifier = tenantIdentifier;
     }
   }
```

Dentro de mi controlador de Java se encuentra así:

```
       User user = userDAO.findOneByUsername(username);
        if(user != null){
         código
         }
```

En este caso la variable user se llena como null.

Gracias, disculpas si no se comprende la pregunta.

Comment: aclarame algo, si el esquema es diferente, significa que el usuario se encuentra en alguna otra tabla verdad? por que no solo mapeas esa tabla? Te lo pregunto de esta forma ya que en postgress no eh ondado mucho, saludos.

Comment: Claro, mira la estructura de cada esquema es idéntica así que la tabla del usuario tiene el mismo nombre. La idea es reconocer a que esquema pertenece determinado usuario. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Del código java no entendí nada; de lo que entendí de tu descripción de lo que tienes en la base: tienes varios esquemas, cada esquema contiene las mismas tablas y cada esquema le pertenece a un usuario distinto. Corrígeme si me equivoco.

Primero aclaremos algo, en postgres los usuarios son objetos globales. Es decir, no están "dentro" de una base ni de un esquema; están por encima de esos objetos.

Ahora, si creaste los esquemas usando un comando como: "CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION usuario" el esquema se creo con el mismo nombre del usuario así que sería fácil ubicar el esquema, si usaste un comando como "CREATE SCHEMA nombre_de_esquema AUTHORIZATION usuario" el usuario sería el dueño del esquema y podrías ubicarlo ejecutando esta consulta: "select nspname from pg_namespace where nspowner = 'usuario'::regrole".

O puedes aclarar un poco más tu pregunta si es que no pude comprender lo que preguntabas.